# String Replacement of [|]^[|] with "\\X1E" is not working in java.while the same is working seamless in linux

Tags: java, shell, delimiter, replaceall

Following is my code.

log.txt  contains [|]^[|] hello

my output both before and after is same..which is [|]^[|] hello

```
String file = "log.txt"

File file = new File(file);

FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

BufferedReader br = new BuffredReader(fr);

while(String s = br.readLine())!=null) {

  System.out.println("before replacing" +s);

  String q = s.replaceAll("[|]^[|]^","hi")

  System.out.println("After replacing :"+q);

}
```

Comment: This is just a test.i would want to replace the multicharecter delimiter with "\\x1E"